# What's the fastest way to remap pixel values in OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a single channel image `gray_image`, with pixels values `[0 .. 255]` and a lookup table mapping those values to colors:

```
lookup = {
 0: [0, 0, 0],
 1: [23, 54, 35],
 ...
 255: [200, 52, 20],
}
```

What is the fastest way to create a new 3 channel image where each pixel is colored based on the lookup of its value in the original images, e.g.

```
color_image[y, x] = lookup[gray_image[y, x]]
```

Instead of iterating through every pixel and setting it individually?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the keys of the lookup table are properly ordered, you could convert the dictionary into an array and then apply NumPy's [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) like this:

```py
import numpy as np

palette = np.array([row for row in lookup.values()])
color_image = palette[gray_image]
```

If the keys of your dictionary are not ordered, the code above won't work. In that case you could convert the dictionary into an array as follows:

```py
palette = np.zeros(shape=(256, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
for key in lookup.keys():
    palette[key] = lookup[key]
```

This approach implicitly defines a default value of `[0, 0, 0]`, i.e. if the lookup table does not contain a certain index, let's say `n`, then those pixels with gray level `n` will be mapped to `[0, 0, 0]` (black).

Answer (score 1):

```py
palette = np.array([lookup[index] for index in range(256)], dtype=np.uint8)
color_image = palette[gray_image]
```

the other answer didn't make sure to sort the dictionary by key (python dicts only recently got a stable order of pairs) and it didn't make sure that all index values exist.

Comment: add at the end line "color_image = color_image.astype('uint8')" because you won't be able to show picture in window.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! I changed the answer and put the type on the palette instead so it saves some space there and removes the need to convert type on the whole picture after it was looked up.

Comment: You have the right approach, but as OP is using OpenCV you can do the lookup using `cv2.LUT()` and it runs around 20x faster on 1920x1080 image on my machine.

Comment: you should post that as an answer

Comment: I don't want to take the points which are clearly yours.